# Close Aurelia Materialize Bridge Modal Programmatically

Tags: modal-dialog, aurelia, materialize

This questions pertains to the Aurelia Materialize Bridge.

Is there any way to close a modal programmatically instead of adding the modal-close class to a button?

For instance, per the documentation, I have the following button in the footer of my modal:

```
<a click.delegate="doSomething()" md-button md-waves class="modal-action modal-close">Ok</a>
```

But, I want to do some validation in 'doSomething()' before closing the modal and prevent it from closing in some cases and close it in others. With the way it is now, 'doSomething()' runs, but the modal closes right away. I see there is an on complete delegate I can set, but that is too late!

Am I missing something or is this a missing feature?

Thanks.

Comment: for what it's worth, i've tried grabbing a reference to the modal using jquery and calling .closeModal()  that doesn't work... console error says closeModal is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jquery 3.1.0 was causing the problem...  when I reverted to jquery 2.2.4, I was able to use

```
$(this.myModal).closeModal();
```

not the first time jquery 3 has screwed me and cost me hours